# Como hacer que mi fecha se vea asi "10 lun"?

Tags: php

estoy haciendo una practica y tengo que hacer que mi fecha se vea en ese formato ósea "día/nombre del día" pero lo tengo que hacer en PHP como puedo hacerlo??
tengo la fecha cargada en una variable pero no se que función utilizar para poder mostrarla en ese formato

```
$dia_fecha = $dato->FECHA;
```

en esa variable tengo guardado la fecha, ahora lo que necesito es saber como mostrarla en el siguiente formato "día/nombre del día", mi fecha esta cargada de la siguiente mantera "año/mes/día". Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pasandole los parametros correctos a la funcion date() puedes obetener ese resultado. Mira puedes intentar de la siguiente manera y adicionalmente te dejo la documentacion de la funcion date(Esto es lo mas optimo en mi opinion, si es que quieres mostrarlo en español): https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php

```
//Primero capturar el dia de la semana siendo 1 lunes y 7 domingo
$day = date("N");
//Ahora capturamos que dia del mes es
$date = date("j");
//Luego un switch para evaluar que dia de la semana es
switch ($day) {
    case '1':
        echo 'La fecha es: Lunes'.' / '.$date;
        break;
    case '2':
        echo 'La fecha es: Martes'.' / '.$date;
        break;
    case '3':
    echo 'La fecha es: Miercoles'.' / '.$date;
        break;
    case '4':
    echo 'La fecha es: Jueves'.' / '.$date;
        break;
    case '5':
    echo 'La fecha es: Viernes'.' / '.$date;
        break;
    case '6':
    echo 'La fecha es: Sabado'.' / '.$date;
        break;
    case '7':
    echo 'La fecha es: Domingo'.' / '.$date;
        break;
    default:
        // code...
        break;
}
```

Comment: gracias Mateo Guio

Answer (score 2):

puedes hacelo asi:

```
function Fecha(){
    $day = date("N")-1;
    $nday = date("j");
    $week= array("lunes" , "martes", "miercoles", "jueves", "viernes" , "sabado","domingo");
    return "{$nday} {$week[$day]}";
}

echo Fecha();
```

Comment: Si verdad, al final lo logre con el ejemplo de Mateo Guio, pero gracias igual

Comment: Me gusta más este estilo. Aunque yo no crearía el objeto  dentro para luego devolver una cadena. Esto será un escollo si el usuario necesita hacer más cosas con el objeto fecha. También, la operación `-1` se puede evitar si usas el formato `w`  que asigna `0` al Domingo.

Answer (score 2):

Si en tu entorno tuvieras instalado el localismo en español podrías hacerlo muy fácilmente con [`setlocale()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.setlocale.php).

Por ejemplo, esto bastaría:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES");
$dateString = "2022/01/27";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y/m/d", $dateString);
echo strftime("%a",$date->getTimestamp());
```

`%a` te dará una representación abreviada del día en Español, si quieres el nombre del día completo, lo cambias por `%A`. Para más detalles ver [`strftime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strftime.php).

Si no tuvieras el localismo disponible, es más natural una solución al estilo de lo propuesto por @Byro, aunque puedes aprovechar la forma en que se indexan los arrays (empezando en el índice `0`), poniendo el domingo como primer elemento del array, y usando el formato `w` que reconoce el Domingo como día `0`.

Ejemplo:

```
$dateString = "2022/01/27";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y/m/d", $dateString);
$daysES=array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado");
printf("%s %s",$date->format('d'),$daysES[$date->format('w')]);
```

**Salida:**

```
27 Jueves
```

Y, si quieres en unos contextos el día con tres letras y en otros el día completo, puedes agregar a tu función utilitaria una bandera (usaremos `L`  y `D`, las mismas que usa PHP), manejar un array asociativo dentro de ellas y sacar los días según esa bandera.

Por ejemplo, la función quedaría así:

```
function spanishDays($n, $format){

    if ($format === 'L' || $format === 'D') {
        $daysES=array(
            "L"=>array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado"),
            "D"=>array("Dom","Lun","Mar","Mié","Jue","Vie","Sáb")
            );
        return $daysES[$format][$n];
    } else {
        throw new Exception("El formato $format no es válido para esta función");
    }

}
```

Ejemplos de uso:

```
printf("%s %s %s",$date->format('d'),spanishDays($date->format('w'),'D'),PHP_EOL);
```

**Salida:**

```
27 Jue
```

---

```
printf("%s %s %s",$date->format('d'),spanishDays($date->format('w'),'L'),PHP_EOL);
```

**Salida:**

```
27 Jueves
```

---

Le pasamos un valor `FAKE` para verificar que nuestra función controla posibles valores falsos.

```
printf("%s %s %s",$date->format('d'),spanishDays($date->format('w'),'FAKE'),PHP_EOL);
```

**Salida:**

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: El formato FAKE no es válido
> para esta función in ... Stack trace:
> #0 325403372/source.php(11): spanishDays('4', 'FAKE')
> #1 {main}   thrown in 325403372/source.php on line 22

Comment: Aunque larga tu respuesta, me parece bastante interesante !

Comment: @MateoGuio he querido mostrar la mejor forma posible, sólo que muchas veces algunos localismos no están instalados en la versión de PHP que se esté usando, por lo que he querido mostrar otra solución alternativa. Y dado que OP refería los días como `Lun` o como `Lunes`, entonces quise mostrar una función que sea flexible. Son por tanto **tres respuestas en una**.

Answer (score 0):

Con `PHP` tienes `date_format(objecto, formato);`

Tienes `$dia_fecha = $dato->FECHA;`

Puedes hacer esto

```
$dia_fecha = date_format($dato->FECHA, "Y/m/d");
```

Comment: si es verdad, pero como puedo mostrarlo en español?

Comment: Quieres mostrarla así, ejemplo: 3/Martes